# Is there a difference between "die Erkennung" and "die Anerkennung"?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Translated they both mean "recognition, identification" (the act of recognizing or fact of being recognized).

Are they synonymous? Is there any difference in usage or meaning? Is one maybe the "older" version of the other? could you write me examples in which one is preferable than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a good answer on the verbs *erkennen* and *anerkennen*. But you asked for the nouns. And they are quite different.

**die Anerkennung**
means recognition, praise. It's expressedly noticing something or someone or someone's acchievements and praising them, showing respect. A frequent phrase is *(jemandem) Anerkennung [zollen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zollen)*.

**die Erkennung**
is almost exclusively used in a technical context, meaning *recognition*, e.g. Mustererkennung (pattern recognition) or Gesichtserkennung (face recognition).

Two other related nouns are

**das Erkennen**
meaning the act of recognizing something or someone and

**die Erkenntnis**
meaning the result of the recognizing process.

Comment: +1, kleiner Einwand aber: _Erkenntnis_ wird kaum im selben Zusammenhang wie _Erkennung_ und _Erkennen_ benutzt (höchstens _Erkennen eines Zusammenhangs_), es ist eher das Ergebnis eines Denk- als eines Erkennungsprozesses.

Answer (score 2):

These are two quite different words. And their meaning also differs whether the object is a person or an object.

**Etwas erkennen** means *to recognize something*, i.e. used to describe the fact of recognizing a far away or very small object.

**Etwas anerkennen** is a term to describe acceptance of a fact or a treaty. Not very often used expression. A government for instance may accept a treaty as valid. That would be

> Die Regierung erkennt den Friedensvertrag an. ([Duden, Fall 2, case 1a is similar but more general](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anerkennen))

Similar here: *akzeptieren*.

**Jemanden anerkennen** (more common: *jemandem Anerkennung entgegenbringen*) means bringing recognition towards somebody, i.e. by complimenting his work.

> Matthias anerkannte Leo, der Bemühungen um eine friedliche Beilegung des Konfliktes unternahm. ([Duden, Fall 1b](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anerkennen))

**Jemanden erkennen** is an old term (used i.e. in the bible) to describe having sex with somebody. Sounds silly if you use it nowadays. It can be used in the first case though, meaning to recognize somebody from a distance or by remembering their face. Compare:

> Als Josef seine Brüder sah, erkannte er sie. (Gen 42,7)
>
> Adam erkannte Eva, seine Frau; sie wurde schwanger und gebar Kain. (Gen 4,1)

Comment: Uhm... could you add one example for "jemanden anerkennen" that would have the meaning that you described? Because I don't think the verb is used that way (structurally speaking)

Comment: @Emanuel: Check the provided duden link. I think that really describes the word in this meaning.

Comment: Well, the thing with the example you added now is that "anerkennen" is connected to a thing. The effort is what's recognized, not Leo. Sure, on a meta level it is Leo but you claim that meaning depends on whether the object is a person or a thing and I don't agree with that. "Matthias anerkannte Leo." based on your explanation this should mean the same as "Matthias brachte Leo Anerkennung entgegen." but to me it doesn't.

Comment: Vielleicht so? Ich bin ehrlich auch nicht so sicher, wie man das einsetzt, aber die verlinkten Beispiele suggerieren schon irgendwas in die Richtung. Dort wird "Die Mitmenschen anerkennen" explizit als Beispiel genannt.

Comment: Für mich ist _anerkennen_ übrigens trennbar (_ich erkenne an_). Ich weiß aber, der Gebrauch schwankt.